# How to get the number of decimal positions of a mysql table column

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the size of decimal position set for a column with decimal type.

I have this value

> decimal(10,3)

That is the `content_type`. I got this by querying the content type of that particular column in `information_schema.columns`

Query I used is

```
$query="SELECT column_name as 'Column Name', 
                data_type as 'Data Type',
                column_type as 'Column Type',
                character_maximum_length as 'Max Length',
                is_nullable as 'Nullable'
                FROM information_schema.columns
                WHERE table_name = '".$table_name."'";
```

And the query is working fine and I got the value `decimal(10,3)` on `$type` with this code.

```
$type = $row['Column Type'];
```

Now what I need to know is, how i can get 3(that is the decimal positions) from this result.

I need this value to figure out the value to be set for the `step` attribute for html5 `input` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html), there should be `NUMERIC_PRECISION` and `NUMERIC_SCALE` fields in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.  `NUMERIC_SCALE` should have the value you want.